# Is it possible to create a Half Circle Bootstrap Sidebar menu using CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working on how I can create a half circle sidebar in my homepage.
Is there a way to create a design like on the example below using bootstrap?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image: Half Circle Sidebar]

Comment: Yes it is possible, but not for someone who "only know the basics of CSS". You may want to search before asking a question here, as described in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

border-radius: 100%;

Then your going to need to nest the contents in a div with padding left, and have the containing div position negative left off the page.

You might also need that in a container with the overflow: hidden.

Here is a basic starter using just plain old bootstrap nav:

https://jsfiddle.net/jeremykenedy/mqhcaz75/1/

CSS:

```
  body {
      background: #163040;
      color: #ffffff;
  }
  #wrapper {
      padding-left: 0;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
      padding-left: 150px;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
      position: fixed;
      left: 224px;
      z-index: 1000;
      overflow-y: auto;
      margin-left: -345px;
      width: 0;
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
      height: 249px;
      overflow: hidden;
      top: 20%;
      box-shadow: inset -1px 0px 100px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4), 1px 0px 100px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .02);
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
      width: 240px;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
      padding: 15px;
      width: 100%;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      margin-right: -250px;
  }
  /* Sidebar Styles */

  .sidebar-nav {
      position: absolute;
      top: 22px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 234px;
      list-style: none;
      padding-left: 128px;
  }
  .sidebar-nav li {
      line-height: 40px;
      margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .sidebar-nav li a {
      display: block;
      width: 246%;
      margin-left: -30px;
      padding-left: 37px;
  }
  .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(1) a {} .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(2) a {
      padding-left: 62px;
  }
  .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(3) a {
      padding-left: 72px;
  }
  .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(4) a {
      padding-left: 62px;
  }
  .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(5) a {} .sidebar-nav li a {
      display: block;
      color: #999999;
      text-decoration: none;
  }
  .sidebar-nav li a:hover {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
  }
  .sidebar-nav li a:active,
  .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
      text-decoration: none;
  }
  .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
      height: 65px;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 60px;
  }
  .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
      color: #999999;
  }
  .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
      background: none;
      color: #fff;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
      #wrapper {
          padding-left: 250px;
      }
      #wrapper.toggled {
          padding-left: 0;
      }
      #sidebar-wrapper {
          width: 250px;
      }
      #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
          width: 0;
      }
      #page-content-wrapper {
          padding: 20px;
      }
      #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
          position: relative;
          margin-right: 0;
      }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span></button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> Messages</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> Help</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Log Out</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form action="#" class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="get">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="query" name="search" placeholder="Search..." type="text" value="">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="toggled" id="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid"></div>
        </div><!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks helpful suggestion

Comment: it's not too bad!